# Adding extra device to namespace using asinfo

Tags: aerospike

From what I saw in the config documentation it’s easy to configure multiple devices within the same name space using:

```
namespace <namespace-name> {
    memory-size <SIZE>G         # Maximum memory allocation for primary
                                # and secondary indexes.
    storage-engine device {     # Configure the storage-engine to use persistence
        device /dev/<device>    # raw device. Maximum size is 2 TiB
        # device /dev/<device>  # (optional) another raw device.
        write-block-size 128K   # adjust block size to make it efficient for SSDs.
    }
}
```

Is there is anyway I can do that without restarting `asd` service? using `asinfo` tool for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot add devices dynamically.

User also posted here:
https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/adding-extra-device-to-namespace-using-asinfo/4525